# Bootstrap grid, content height fill

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wonder how can I achieve in Bootstrap 3-row grid layout, with content row fills screen size ( and header and footer are fixed height ).

Here is an image what I am trying to achieve:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you really want that middle div to fill the screen or just the footer to be stuck to the bottom?

Comment: I want the middle div to stop just before bottom footer ( so whole container fills the screen, not the middle div ).

Comment: The problem is that you don't know the size of the screen. What happens when your middle div contents are larger than the screen size? Or smaller?

Comment: Is the footer supposed to be fixed to the bottom?

Comment: @CharlesIngalls yes, because site should be exact height of the browser-height ( without any scrolling enabled )

Comment: @DavidG that is something I can assume from the desing

Comment: @JurnyWiedzmin You didn't answer my question, what happens if the content is LARGER that the window height?

Comment: @JurnyWiedzmin People can resize their browser, you cannot rely on a fixed size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would nest the header and footer within a content div and set this content div to 100% height with a top and bottom padding that equals the height of the header/footer.

**Example 1: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/6841/**

**Example 2 (with Bootstrap columns): http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/6842/**

**Example 3 (with scrollable inner container): http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/6843/**

**HTML**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.content {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 40px 0;
    background: yellow;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background: black;
}

.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background: black;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I had ready in a jsFiddle. OP still needs to confirm what happens when content is too large though...

Comment: In other words, does it need an `overflow: scroll;` on the content? :)

Comment: You can make the inner container scrollable. Updated my answer! :)

Comment: That's better, I won't bother posting mine now :)

Comment: @CharlesIngalls nice answer, that is what I was thinking about :)

Comment: @DavidG I realised that your question is crucial after I left my house. Scroll behaviour should do